# How can I configure a single-node cluster on RHEL 7?

Tags: linux, redhat, cluster, high-availability, rhel7

For particular purposes, I'd like to know how can I configure a RHEL 7 HA cluster with only one node (of course, no HA will be available in this scenario).

The following article says that single-node clusters are not supported:
https://access.redhat.com/articles/5892

By the way, in the RedHat customers portal there is a page that explains how to make a single-node cluster in RHEL 6, so I'm quite sure there is a way to do the same thing in RHEL 7.

My personal approach would apply the following settings:

Cluster CIB:

```
[...]
<nodes>
    <node id="1" uname="clusternode1"/>
</nodes>
[...]
```

Corosync configuration:

```
[...]
nodelist {
    node {
        ring0_addr: clusternode1
        nodeid: 1
    }
}
[...]
```

but I'm not sure this is the right and sufficient way to get what I need.
Thanks in advance for any precious hint.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi @ewwhite, I'd just like to create a RHEL 7 cluster with only one node. Further nodes may be added in the future but, initially, I have only one machine so I need to configure a single-node cluster, and I'd like to know if this is possibile since the "theory" considers a minimum number of two machines when speaking about clusters (and HA, LB, and so on).